# Destroy / Restart a different session in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, session-state

I always found solutions to my problems here, but I'm missing something for this one. Here's my problem:

I have a login.php page which redirects people to different pages depending on their status (member, expert, admin). The type of the button is a submit button:

`<input type="submit" name="LOGIN"` ...

I get all the info (login, password) of the form in my PHP using :

`if(isset($_POST['LOGIN'])) {` ...

And the user is redirected to its page with certain privileges.

But if the user has the status "member", that means it's his first visit and he has to go to an intermediate page (loginNewMb.php)  using  `Header("Location: loginNewMb.php");` to enter his coordinates (name, company...). Then, he will have the status "registered member" and he will be able to go to his data.php?member=XXX page. But when he enters to the loginNewMb page, he's still in the session coming from the login.php page. So I need to close it and create a new one depending on the info he will provide. Hope you're still with me.

I was just wondering if you could please guide me as the best strategy to do that. How and in which files should I destroy / restart a new sessions? Is there a better way to do that? I don't necessarily need some codes, just some clues to guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure, you can put the following at the beginning of your `loginNewMn.php` file.

```php
            /** clear session variable */
            session_unset();
            /** destroy the session */
            session_destroy();
            /** end the current session and store session data. */
            session_write_close();
            /** clear cookies */
            setcookie(session_name(), '', ['expires' => 0, 'path' => '/']);
            /** clear old session id */
            session_regenerate_id(true);
    
            /** start the (new) session */ 
            session_start();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm cleaning everything with that and can start with a fresh new session.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `session_destroy()` and `session_regenerate_id(true)` on top of the `loginNewMb.php` page.

Or you can unset specific `$_SESSION` variables using `$_SESSION["foo"]`

Or, you can just do it in the `login.php` before redirecting.

---

### Note:

After you use `session_destroy()`, you have to use `session_start()` again to use `$_SESSION` variables.

Doing that with JS would not be really good, because any user can disable JS. So, using PHP is the best method.